# Gitignore not ignoring target folder in scala sbt project

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore file looks like this, however it is not ignoring target folder,

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so

#Compiled target packages
######################
target/
project/target/
.idea/
.idea
.idea/workspace.xml
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks good. But if it is not ignoring folder than delete folder once and then try to run again.

Answer (score 3):

You probably added .gitignore file after the target folder creation.

Be careful before doing this for unchecked files. Then use this command at your project.

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

After this operation, you may need to commit for removing all undesirable files at repository.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'send with gitignore activation.'
```